# How to display custom token on Mainnet Monitor?

Tags: eosio.token

Let`s assume that I deployed eosio.token to my own account, created some tokens there.
I would like to know if it is possible for tokens on that account to be displayed in Account info on EOS Mainnet Monitor.

Comment: What do you mean with EOS Mainnet Monitor?

Comment: @PhillipHamnett-EOS42, I mean https://eosnetworkmonitor.io/

Answer (score 2):

This should happen automatically as long as you follow the format of the eosio.token contract. The two most important things are that you have the tables from the eosio.token contract:

- `accounts`
- `stats`

Which must have at least the following fields:

#### accounts

```
    {
        "name": "account",
        "base": "",
        "fields": [
            {
                "name": "balance",
                "type": "asset"
            }
        ]
    }
```

#### stats

```
    {
        "name": "currency_stats",
        "base": "",
        "fields": [
            {
                "name": "supply",
                "type": "asset"
            },
            {
                "name": "max_supply",
                "type": "asset"
            },
            {
                "name": "issuer",
                "type": "name"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Open your command line and paste this: curl -X GET 'https://api.eospark.com/api?module=account&action=get_token_list&apikey=a9564ebc3289b7a14551baf8ad5ec60a&account= mainnet account name'
Just add your account name at the last, instead of mainnet account name.